# What is an unrestricted production?

Tags: formal-grammars

I was reading an article at

[What does "context" in "context-free grammar" refer to?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42988/what-does-context-in-context-free-grammar-refer-to)

The production

```
zA -> xy
```

is described as being an "unrestricted" production. In what way is it "unrestricted"?

I even visited https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unrestricted_grammar

which talks about unrestricted grammar as the one that is comprised of productions which have no restriction on LHS or RHS. On this note, I assume that an unrestricted production is the one with no restriction on LHS or RHS.

What restrictions are being talked about and how is the production free from such restrictions?

Answer (score 2):

A single rule can not be "unrestricted".

The *whole* set of rules is $(T \cup N)^+ \to (T \cup N)^*$. So the *class* of unrestricted grammars may use any rule from this set.

*Restricted* classes of grammars are only allowed to use a strict subset of all rles, e.g.

- right-regular grammars are restricted to $N \to T^*N^{\{0,1\}}$, and
- context-free grammars to $N \to (T \cup N)^*$.

By going through the Chomsky hierarchy, you will note that the rule

$\qquad zA \to xy$

is not admitted in any but the type-0 grammars; try to see why it's not a "context-sensitive rule". That does not mean it is *only ever* allowed in the unrestricted class -- just that it's not in any *on this list*. There are many more classes.